# Sprocketsfilter in assetic - requirements and example

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, sprockets, assetic

I'm working with Symfony 2 with Twig and assetic file manager.
I have high number of javascript files that have many dependencies. (Javascript prototypal inheritance)

I saw sprockets in action, and I see that assetic has also sprocketsfilter to manage dependencies.

Do I need anything more that I already have (php)? (I believe sprockets were orginally created for ruby)

I'd like to see an example of using it together, for example 5 js files (containing function that requires previous one)

Comment: Ok i found that this plugin requires ruby, so there is no way to use it (by me). Alternatives? https://github.com/stuartloxton/php-sprockets